# MySQL grouping by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, message

I'm trying to return back all the messages for a user_id ( 1 ) in the table sorted by created_at desc, but have it grouped by sender_id or recipient_id depending on whichever created_at is newer.

```
messages
sender_id | recipient_id | text | created_at
1 | 2 | hey | 2017-03-26 04:00:00
1 | 2 | tees | 2017-03-26 00:00:00
2 | 1 | rrr | 2017-03-27 00:00:00
3 | 1 | edd | 2017-03-27 00:00:00
1 | 3 | cc3 | 2017-02-27 00:00:00
```

Ideally it would return

```
2 | 1 | rrr | 2017-03-27 00:00:00
1 | 3 | cc3 | 2017-02-27 00:00:00
```

The query I have so far is -

```
select *
from messages
where (
        sender_id = 1
        or recipient_id = 1
        )
group by least(sender_id, recipient_id)
order by created_at desc
```

but it seems it is doing the order by before the group by.

Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: order by least(...)

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is intended for aggregation (sum, count, etc...), the fact that it orders is little more than an official side effect (that is being deprecated, and not guaranteed behavior in future versions). `ORDER BY` is done after `GROUP BY`, it sorts the final results, and can take multiple expressions. Your interchangeable use of the terms makes it difficult to understand exactly what you are looking for, but going by sample desired results this is probably it:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), created_at DESC
```

However, since all rows in your sample result have the same "LEAST" value, it could be this:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to get the most recent post by user 1 where they are a sender and the most recent post by user 1 where they are a recipient.

I would do a union with the first query getting the most recent post as a sender and the second getting the most recent post as a recipient.

```
select * 
from messages
join
(
select 
    sender_id,
    max(created_at) as max1
from messages 
where
    sender_id = 1
group by
    sender_id
) t1
on messages.created_at = t1.max1

union

select * 
from messages
join
(
select 
    recipient_id,
    max(created_at) as max2
from messages 
where
    recipient_id = 1
group by
    recipient_id
) t2
on messages.created_at = t2.max2
```